# How to access programmatically what is displayed in an Android lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen, htc-android, htc-hero

Today I am looking for a way to mimic the behavior I know from my HTC Hero's lock screen: the calendar and alarm clock can put text & drawables there to inform about an upcoming event or an expired alarm. The lock screen remains there in that it must be dragged down to dismiss the shown event and there might also be a Snooze button.

But, first question: is this default Android stuff or HTC Sense specific only??
Second question: If it is a common Android thing, why can't I find anything in Google's Android documentation for the topics "lockscreen" or "lock screen" that comes close to my question? Where's the API for it?

My problem is: I want to inform the user immediately - even if I try a standard notification, the user with a locked screen will have to unlock it and drag down the notifications list to see & clear what's going on. *sigh* Putting an endlessly playing notification sound there is a hassle as it takes at least two swipes down to stop the sound playing!

Any hints on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this default Android stuff or HTC
>   Sense specific only?

It is HTC Sense only. You cannot modify the lock screen of the device from SDK code -- only via firmware modifications. Sorry!

Comment: So, on "pure" Android systems nothing will ever be shown on a lock screen? Nothing? That's really lame... ;-)
But didn't HTC release their source code, too? No way to at least give HTC users this experience in my software?

Comment: "So, on 'pure' Android systems nothing will ever be shown on a lock screen?" Android 2.1 shows the date, time, and status bar (and possibly other things tied to features I don't use). It's just not configurable by SDK applications. "But didn't HTC release their source code, too?" Not for HTC Sense. "No way to at least give HTC users this experience in my software?" AFAIK, there is no SDK add-on from HTC to allow you to customize HTC Sense lock screens.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of o long way around the problem...
but the wallpaper is shown on then lockscreen. so you clould write a custom wallpaper to display your info on the lockscreen. (i think).